# How to change the color of hyperlink after click it

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of the hyperlink after clicking on it, but remaining hyperlinks color are also changed..

#### CSS

```
a:active {
    color: gray;
}
a:visited {
    color:black;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<body> 
    <a href="link1.html">a</a>
    <a href="link2.html">b</a>
    <a href="link3.html">c</a> 
</body>
```

Comment: Is your website static? You want to highlight current page or what?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour ? cause the one you describe is perfectly normal

Comment: I just want to change the color of hyperlink after clicking on it..

Comment: it is working fine, i tried it on IE6

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar i am using firefox it is not working ..

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar its not appropriate to clear the history every time.so can i know is it possible to get every time a fresh page without changing the color of hyperlink..

Answer (score 11):

The `:visited` pseudo-class works on the browser's history. The fact that all three links are being drawn with the black colour means that your browser has visited them in the past. If you were to clear your history, or change the links' urls, you'll find that they aren't classed as 'visited'.

A [link to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) will probably show as visited in your browser, but a [link to Voice of JIHAD](http://shahamat-english.com/) probably shows up a different colour (unless you are a member of the Taliban). Clicking on the unvisited link will change its colour to the visited colour - as defined in Stack Overflow's stylesheets - and will remain 'visited' as long as the page exists in your browser's history.

Comment: I tried what you are saying but when i clicked on link the other link colors are also changed... that's the problem..

Comment: Are you sure that all three links have three different `href` attributes?

Comment: yes i am using diff href's for diff links..

Comment: and are all three links not in your browser history? if you changed the links to link1-changed.html, link2-changed.html, link3-changed.html, what is the outcome?

Comment: its not appropriate to clear the history every time.so can i know is it possible to get every time a fresh page without changing the color of hyperlink

Comment: You could use a scripting language like JavaScript or PHP to append a random querystring to the end of the href.

Comment: let me know how to do that...with javascript and help me how to clear history every time.. and if i include the php tags in html and what to include in the php

Comment: Is php headers helpful to clear history?

Comment: I think this is a separate question, off topic here.

Comment: But how can i clear the browser history every time when the page loads..

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat

Comment: Can you give me one best way among them.. i don't how to do that.. provide me if you have any solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31653/discussion-between-greg-and-kvk-ganesh)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so now you know that `:visited` works from the browser history, and I think you want to change the color of the clicked link only.
I put some jQuery together

```
$('a').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("visited");
});
```

and the CSS

```
a{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

a.visited{
color:#205081;
}
```

**Update:**

```
  ....
  ....
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>// import jQuery
  <script>
  enter the script here..
  </script>
  </body>
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfTXe/)

Comment: so where i need to include the jquery...

Comment: just before close the `body` tag, see update

Comment: @KvkGanesh same problem is here. But with sub-menus. When a sub-menu is clicked it remains white, but I need that its main menu option should also remain white.

Comment: @Kvk Ganesh same problem is here. But with sub-menus. When a sub-menu is clicked it remains white, but I need that its main menu option should also remain white.