# Changing color of hyperlink in HTML

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an angular2 application. I am using a hyperlink to call a method which opens a small pop up window. I tried various ways to change the color of the link when clicked but it's not working.

Code snippet is as following:

HTML:

```
<td> <a *ngIf="(books.status== 'FAILED')" (click)="openWindow(books.id)">{{books.id}}</a></td>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color: blue;
}
a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: can we get a working example orr a live one?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in the following way:

```
/* selected link */
a:active { 
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: This only changes color between the time it's clicked and the sub window opens. I want the link to stay red even after the window closes.

Answer (score 1):

Add following CSS class in your css file:

```
.visitedLinkColor{
         color : blue;  }
```

Try this for Angular 1.5

```
        <td>
            <a href
               ng-click="visited = true"
               ng-class="{'visitedLinkColor': visited ==true}">
                {{books.id}}
            </a>
        </td>
```

For Angular 2

```
        <td>
            <a *ngIf="(books.status== 'FAILED')"
               (click)="visited = true"
               (class)=" {'visitedColor': visited == true}">
            {{books.id}}
            </a>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

The simplest I think is

```
<td> <a *ngIf="(books.status== 'FAILED')" (click)="openWindow(books.id)" [style.color]="visitedColor">{{books.id}}</a></td>
```

In your component add a variable, in constructor,

`visitedColor: string = 'blue';`

then in the method `openWindow` which is triggered on click, set the value as RED

`this.visitedColor = 'red';`

PS: Remove your CSS to see its working. This solution does not need CSS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Argument of type visitedColor:String is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'visitedColor' does not exist in type 'Component'

Comment: Sorry I was adding that line to @Component. But now after making correct changes, it's changing the color of all the links along with the link which is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use :

```
a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This only changes color between the time it's clicked and the sub window opens. I want the link to stay red even after the window closes.

Answer (score 0):

:visited pseudo-class should work fine for this. But by the comment you said in one of the answers, you expect it to be change even if you closed and then reopened the browser. This should happen as well since :visited pseudo-class should have been saved in your browser history. Unless, maybe you are doing a hard reset, or clearing your browser history? or maybe you are browsing in "private/incognito" mode?

This might be Helpful for you. [How to change the color of hyperlink after click it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062608/how-to-change-the-color-of-hyperlink-after-click-it). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you have to write this code

```
    td > a:link {
      color : blue;
    }
    td > a:visited {
      color : red;
   }
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Did you write td tag and inside td tag you have to write anchor tag

Comment: That's invalid CSS. You can't add arbitrary spaces to selectors. It's also completely lacking anything resembling an explanation as to why it should solve the problem.