# Link text color not changing after being visited

Tags: html, css

I'm working with HTML and CSS, and am trying to write a link that directs the user to a new tab. I want the link color change to a specific color I want after being visited, but it somehow remains the color I set for being visited from the beginning, **even before it's been visited**, and it won't change. How can I fix this? I've looked up online but it still doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>related</title>
   <style>
      #related_link {
          color: #DED7EC;
          font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 30px;
          margin-bottom: 150px;
          text-align: left;
      }

      #related {
         color: #640344;
    
    
      }

      #related:visited {
         color: red;
         background-color: #91A7FA;
      }

      #related:hover {
         background-color: blue;
      }

   </style>


</head>
<body>
   <div id="related_link">
      <h3>Related Topics:</h3>
      <a id="related" href="new.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Click Here To Be Directed To A New Tab</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have already visited the link, it will show as visited. That doesn't typically get reset when you reload the page. Clearing your cache, however, may reset that.

Comment: @user1599011 Whoops, then is there a way to reset it after the website/tab is closed? Can I use some JS or anything?

Comment: Are you sure you haven’t visited these sites already? Have you tried from a different browser or device?

Comment: Don't rely on that as a UI strategy. Use database or browser storage instead. (Most websites mask visited links anyway since that information isn't often useful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The :visited pseudo-class works on the browser's history. The fact that all three links are being drawn with the black colour means that your browser has visited them in the past. If you were to clear your history, or change the links' urls, you'll find that they aren't classed as 'visited'.

A link to Stack Overflow will probably show as visited in your browser, but a link to Voice of JIHAD probably shows up a different colour (unless you are a member of the Taliban). Clicking on the unvisited link will change its colour to the visited colour - as defined in Stack Overflow's stylesheets - and will remain 'visited' as long as the page exists in your browser's history.

Related Question: [How to change the color of hyperlink after click it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062608/how-to-change-the-color-of-hyperlink-after-click-it)

Credit to Greg for this answer.

Comment: I didn't know that, I thought it would be reset to unvisited after the browser is closed... So, is there a way to manually set a reset after the page is closed? Like, as long as the page is open it'd change the color of the links I've clicked, and after I close the page and open it again it would all have been set to unvisited again?

Comment: To do that you would have to clear your browsers cache, like user1599011 said.

Comment: Of course, but what about the user? I Should they also clear their browser cache themselves? Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I don't know if this would work, but you could try it. Basically, when the user first opens the site, make the link red. Then, set up a onclick listener, and when the user clicks on the link, dynamically change it.

Comment: <a href='asdf' id='test'>Link Here</a> JS document.getElementById('test').onclick(blah) function blah() document.getElementById('test').style.color='purple'. This code is not correct, but it is an example of what you could do.